# Javascript HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, java, html, htmlunit

I have a submit button that I can't click on..

```
<div class="button_green">
    <a href="javascript:sendSMS();" title="Send SMS"><span>Send SMS</span></a>
</div>
```

I have tried this:

```
page = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Send SMS").click();
```

but that won't work.

Is there a way to click on this or run the Javascript with Java and HtmlUnit?
And it is not my site, so can't do anything with the html-code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath:

```
page = htmlPage.<HtmlDivision>getFirstByXPath("//div[@class='button_green'").click();
```

Which means: search for the first `div` with a `class` attribute of `button_green`, and click it.

W3schools has a good [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```html
<script>
  function sendSMS(){
    alert('your sms function work here~~');
  }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:sendSMS();" title="Send SMS"><span>Send SMS</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the button tag like this:

```
<button type="button">Send SMS</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot edit HTML then you can do this using jquery. Try following code.

```js
$( ".button_green" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button_green">
    <a href="javascript:sendSMS();" title="Send SMS"><span>Send SMS</span></a>
</div>
```

To enable jquery first add a script line in the HTML page.